# Make wget convert absolute links along with relative links

Tags: download, website, wget

I'm trying to back up a site using `wget`.  Currently I'm running

```
wget -p --mirror --html-extension --convert-links http://www.example.com`.
```

`--convert-links` behaves just as expected with some links, such as converting links to `/about` to `/about.html`.  However, for some reason `wget` is converting a lot of the links to links to the main site, like `/calendar` to `http://www.example.com/calendar`.

Why is this happening, and how can I make `wget` reference the local files instead of going back to the original website?